# Mac not connecting to Internet, but Safari is connecting to Internet

Tags: network, wifi, safari, internet

Have this weird wireless network, once the mac connected to the network, everything except safari shows offline (Skype, Spotify, Dropbox and other apps) an even when I `ping google.com` or `ping 8.8.8.8` all results in timeout.

But for some weird reason safari can still browse internet for known domains, and soon as I try to resolve an unknown domain, it can't find that host.

Pretty sure this is an DNS issue, but none of the other devices in the network has this issue. I tried flushing DNS of the mac, and using google DNSs but no luck

Can't even reset the mac to factory settings without a internet connection at this point

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the model of modem/router you're using and how it's configured? Also, what version of macOS are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by known or unknown domain?

Comment: OP! Please elaborate on "But for some weird reason safari can still browse internet for known domains, and soon as I try to resolve an unknown domain, it can't find that host."

Comment: You've asked the same question twice. Only ask it once.